# ¿Cómo ocultar una columna con Bootstrap4 cuando se achica la resolución?

Tags: bootstrap

¿De qué manera se podría ocultar una columna de una tabla con bootstrap4 cuando se cambia la resolución de la pantalla a una menor? Por ejemplo, en la siguiente tabla, ocultar la columna con "Lat, Lng" cuando se achica el browser:

El código de la tabla es normal:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Place Name</th>
    <th>[ Lat, Lng ]</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let place of places">
   <td>{{ place.address  }}</td>
   <td><small>[ {{ place.latitude }}, {{ place.longitude }} ]</small></td>
   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="viewPlace(place)"><span class="fa fa-search-plus fa-lg"></span> view</button></td>
   <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="deletePlace(place)"><span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></span> delete</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega la clase `hidden-md-down` al elemento `<th>` y `<td>` correspondientes. La clase indica que deberán ocultarse dichos elementos en resoluciones *medium* o menores, lo que corresponde a las resoluciones: *extra-small*, *small* y *medium*.

En [esta página](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#available-classes) puedes ver las distintas clases *helper* que ayudan a ocultar contenido de tu página dependiendo de la resolución actual del cliente.

A continuación pongo una imagen de las resoluciones existentes (saltos) en el sistema de *grid* de Bootstrap 4 (puede consultarse [aquí](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

La clase `hidden-md-down` no me funcionó en bootstrap 4.
Utilicé la clases `d-none` y `d-md-block`. `d-none` oculta siempre, pero `d-md-block` muestra en dispositivos de tamaño mediano hacia arriba.

Para más información: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/